# Loading content and project layout in XNA

Tags: c#, xna

I'm kinda confused with how XNA does things

So I'm trying to make the following layout in an XNA project:
[image: Overview]

```
.cs = file
<*>(); = list
new *(); = object
" : " = an inheritance
*(folder) = folder (I think you probably figured that one out)
```

in Box.cs the texture of the box is loaded (same for wall)
so when I do new box(); I only need to specify the position.

But I have no clue what to use for each file, and where to call what, or how I load my textures ( I tried in `LoadContent()` but that isn't always called in the right moment.)

I tried searching for projects which have a similar layout to figure out these things but I couldn't really find a good one, or I don't type the right keywords.

Could someone provide me with an explanation on how and where I should do things? 
Or if you're really generous, a project in which this layout exists and only the textures of the active level are loaded (for example: wall is not loaded until lvl 2)

if something is unclear, feel free to ask, I'll try to explain a bit more.

Comment: I'm sorry but I doubt you will have a lot of answers to your question. Try to split it in multiple parts. Examples: "How do I load a texture in XNA?", ...

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure that you load all your textures before you attempt to draw them, When you're switching levels should do.

IF your game doesn't have that much content, what I've done before is loaded all of the textures in a static `Dictionary<String, Texture2D>` in `LoadContent()`, and then every object, instead of having a texture, had a `string` key to that dictionary.

Comment: Yea, that's one way, I was thinking about loading them static, so I can paint the same image over and over again, without having to load the same image in the memory for every time I want to use it

Comment: @Kiwi Keep in mind that the ContentManager keeps an internal cache of loaded objects, so if you ask it to load the same texture multiple times, it can quickly retrieve it instead of having to load it in again.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have been searching some more, and I was able to get a student license on XBOX live indie game thingy,

And there I found an demo project + Tutorial (double win!) gonna look into that tomorrow, but that should be enough to get started with my project :)